# Bulk process invoices with QuickBooks SDK including cover letter

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc, qbxml

Is there a way to print, via the SDK (I'm using qbXML and the QuickBooks web connector to connect to a Java application server, SDK version 7.0, QuickBooks enterprise 9.0) invoices with their cover letter? It may take a third party tool, because it seems that QuickBooks has a nice little checkbox of "to be printed" which lets you go and print them one by one from the reminders window and little else (you can print the invoice in bulk, and labels in bulk this way, but not cover letters)?

As an alternative, some way of flagging the invoice created via the SDK on creation so that it can be printed with the appropriate cover letter later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this is via a very tight Quickbooks UI event integration, and even then it would be challenging. The QuickBooks SDK basically supports the UI functionality (or really a subset thereof, but a large subset). The UI has no way of specifying a cover letter on the to be printed invoices, unless you do it manually one by one, so there is no way to do it via the SDK.

If there is a third party tool to do this, I was unable to find one.

Comment: I've created apps that integrate with QuickBooks using QODBC and RSSBus. They are MUCH easier to interact with than the SDK (I personally prefer RSSBus) I believe you could create a pretty simple app to do this using RSSBus

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch the invoice data from QuickBooks via the SDK and write your own PDF generation routine to batch-print the invoices... it wouldn't make use of the QuickBooks PDF generation stuff nor the actual QuickBooks templates however.